# Why VSCode is code is not taking commands

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Help me with this please. I don't know why the code is not taking command

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't be related vs code. you using sr.Microphone through python.exe not vs code. Try without VSCode and if it does not work, check your sr.Microphone variable.